# Pandas dataframe values not changing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, neural-network

I am currently getting my toes wet with neural nets, using colaboratory, pandas and keras. To set up my data, I need to normalize all the data (for which I am getting all values between 0 and 1 by dividing by the largest value). However, I've run into 2 issues.

1. For some reason, the column "stroke_count" isn't being modified, or if it is it's being round down to 0 no matter what.
2. I saw that 
   df.fillna(7)
   supposedly replaces all Null or NaN values with the value inside the parenthesis, but it isn't doing that.

   ```
   # generating character dictionary & normalizing data

   hanzi_dict = {}

   hanzi_counter = 0

   df.fillna(7)
   for index, row in df.iterrows():
       hanzi_dict[str(hanzi_counter)] = row['charcter']
       hanzi_counter = hanzi_counter + 1

       df.at[index, 'radical_code'] = row['radical_code'] / 214.9 # max value of any radical
       df.at[index, 'stroke_count'] = row['stroke_count'] / 35.0    # max # of strokes
       df.at[index, 'hsk_levl'] = row['hsk_levl'] / 7             # max level + 1

   print(hanzi_dict) 

   display(df)
   ```

Comment: for fillna, you are not actually changing df. so you need to do df = df.fillna(7) or, the more correct way would be df.fillna(7, inplace=True). can you show us part of df before the loop so we know what it looks like?

Comment: @db702 thank you! That fixed the issue around not replacing the NaN values

Comment: Don't use `inplace`, it's going to be deprecated :)